# Django check if any attr matches in a query

Tags: python, html, django

I have a "search" form, which searches for objects in my DB.
This form has two fields, a Select (ChoiceField) where users can select which attribute they are searching by, and a text field they can fill.

For example I can select "Search by name", and I type "Matt", so it will search for value "Matt" on column "name".
Also I can search by other attrs.

Everything work fine until here. The problem comes when I try to use my last search option, "Search by any coincidence", which should query for a match in any of the columns.

forms.py:

```
class BuscarAuxi(forms.Form):
    busqPor = forms.ChoiceField(
        required=False,
        widget=forms.Select,
        choices=SEARCH_AUXI,
    )
    criterio = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    busqPor.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
    criterio.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control col-7 m-2', 'placeholder': 'Criterio'})
```

views.py:

```
def crudAuxi(request):
if request.method == "GET":
form = BuscarAuxi(request.GET)
print('Get method. ')
print(form.errors)
if form.is_valid():
    print(Valid form. ')
    print(form.cleaned_data.get('busqPor'))
    critBusqueda = form.cleaned_data.get('criterio')
    tipoBusqueda = form.cleaned_data.get('busqPor')
    if tipoBusqueda == '1':
        try:
            busqueda = Auxi.objects.get(denom=critBusqueda)
            if busqueda:
                print('Matched by name. ')
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            print('Not found by name. ')
    if tipoBusqueda == '2':
        try:
            busqueda = Auxi.objects.get(nroDoc=critBusqueda)
            if busqueda:
                print('Matched by DNI. ')
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            print('Not found by DNI. ')
    if tipoBusqueda == '3':
        try:
            busqueda = Auxi.objects.get(cuit=critBusqueda)
            if busqueda:
                print('Matched by CUIT. ')
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            print('Not found by CUIT. ')
    if tipoBusqueda == '4':
        try:
            busqueda = Auxi.objects.get(tele=critBusqueda)
            if busqueda:
                print('Matched by phone number. ')
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            print('Not found by phone number. ')
    if tipoBusqueda == '5':
        try:
            busqueda = Auxi.objects.get(critBusqueda)
            if busqueda:
                print('Found by any attr. ')
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            print('Not found by any attr. ')
```

Options from 1 to 4 work properly, but option 5 is not working (I know I have a wrong syntaxis in this option), I'm trying to figure how to search for a match in any column/attr

Comment: busqueda = Auxi.objects.get(`something`=critBusqueda)

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan so it means that I have to code all of my columns as "something=critBusqueda"

Comment: cases 1-4 will also throw a `Auxi.DoesNotExist` or `Auxi.MultipleObjectsReturned` exception because you're using `get()` instead of `filter()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter()` in order to avoid using `try except` and if you want to check if it only exists or not you can user `exists()` that will return you boolean.

```
from django.db.models import Q

if form.is_valid():
    print('Valid form. ')
    print(form.cleaned_data.get('busqPor'))
    critBusqueda = form.cleaned_data.get('criterio')
    tipoBusqueda = form.cleaned_data.get('busqPor')
    if tipoBusqueda == '1':
        busqueda = Auxi.objects.filter(denom=critBusqueda).exists()
        if busqueda:
            print('Matched by name. ')
        else:
            print('Not found by name. ')
    if tipoBusqueda == '2':
        busqueda = Auxi.objects.filter(nroDoc=critBusqueda).exists()
        if busqueda:
            print('Matched by DNI. ')
        else:
            print('Not found by DNI. ')
    if tipoBusqueda == '3':
        busqueda = Auxi.objects.filter(cuit=critBusqueda).exists()
        if busqueda:
            print('Matched by CUIT. ')
        else:
            print('Not found by CUIT. ')
    if tipoBusqueda == '4':
        busqueda = Auxi.objects.filter(tele=critBusqueda).exists()
        if busqueda:
            print('Matched by phone number. ')
        else:
            print('Not found by phone number. ')
    if tipoBusqueda == '5':
        busqueda = Auxi.objects.filter(
            Q(column1=critBusqueda) |
            Q(column2=critBusqueda) |
            Q(column3=critBusqueda) |
        ).exists()
        if busqueda:
            print('Found by any attr. ')
        else:
            print('Not found by any attr. ')
```

In `5` case you check if `column1`, `column2` or `column3` matches your query. Where `column1`, `column2` and `column3` are your fields.